# Installing non-bower-ready library with Bower

Tags: bower, cloudinary

I am using Bower (http://bower.io/) to manage my app's third-party libraries and now I want to use a library which doesn't have a registered bower package, namely `jquery.cloudinary.js` from Cloudinary (http://cloudinary.com).

I would really love to include **cloudinary** amongst my bower-managed libraries because it really helps cloning my development environment when I need to.

Is it possible to install any library available in the internet with Bower by just editing my `bower.json` file? If so, how?

I guess I could either ask Cloudinary to create and register a Bower package or do it myself but I am still in doubt whether I should do any of these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register it or install with the git url directly: `bower install http://website.com/repo.git`

From the [Bower readme](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/README.md):

> Bower offers several ways to install packages:
>
> Using a local or remote package
>
> ```
> bower install <package>
> ```
>
> Where `<package>` can be any one of the following:
>
> A name that maps to a package registered with Bower, e.g, jquery. ‡
>
> **A remote Git endpoint, e.g., git://github.com/someone/some-package.git. Can be public or private. ‡**
>
> A local endpoint, i.e., a folder that's a Git repository. ‡
>
> A shorthand endpoint, e.g., someone/some-package (defaults to GitHub). ‡
>
> A URL to a file, including zip and tar files. Its contents will be extracted.