# Add canvasjs library that does not exist in bower to my project

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

I would like to use CanvasJS library in my project but it does not exist in bower packages, so I tried to install it from a local zip file that I downloaded from their [website](http://canvasjs.com/). After successful installation the bower.json file includes the library's version and local path

```
"canvasjs-1.9.8": "C:\\path\\to\\myfolder\\canvasjs-1.9.8.zip"
```

Then if I try to build the project using ***gulp*** (e.g gulp serve), the library is not automatically added in the  of index.html, as it happens for all the other libraries.

Is it a problem that it was installed from a local file? Is there another way to add CanvasJS library to my project and to my index.html file which is automatically generated with gulp build?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bower installation I followed the instructions of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796401/installing-non-bower-ready-library-with-bower), and I assumed that using the .zip file that I downloaded would work. Since it didn't, the solution was to unistall it, un-compress the zip file and install the local .js file of the library. Then gulp serve command included the library in the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-inject` in order to automatically inject code inside your index for example. Here the link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

So you can manually download your library (please include the .js version not the .zip), put it inside your project and dynamically include it inside the index using that plugin, adding a new task inside your gulp serve/build process.

You can also think to provide support for the library in the bower repository. It will make it available through bower to you and to the other users too in the future, if they may need it.
If you want to create a bower package, please refer to the official documentation that is really well done:

https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This library doesn't have a Github repo so I think that I can't register it with bower. Also I read the documentation for gulp-inject but I couldn't understand how this could help. Sorry but I'm new to javascript projects and these build concepts in general.

Comment: You can create a github repo in 5 minutes. Just register on github and start a new repo. It is free 
About the plugin it's a plugin in order to dynamically inject stuffs with gulp. You mention gulp in your answer. So actually you can manually download the js. Put the js inside a folder of your project. Tells to gulp to inject that library inside the index when serving/building